# How can I prevent an Option<T> from being moved when I reassign it?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::stdin;
use std::io::stdout;
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::io::Write;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};
use std::path::Path;
use std::process::Child;
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;
use std::str;

fn process_line(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut commands = input.trim().split(" | ").peekable();
    let mut previous_command = None;
    let mut resultat = String::new();

    while let Some(command) = commands.next() {
        let mut parts = command.trim().split_whitespace();
        let mut command = parts.next().unwrap();
        let args = parts;

        match command {
            //[...]
            command => {
                if commands.peek().is_some() {
                    let stdin = match previous_command {
                        None => Stdio::inherit(),
                        Some(o) => o,
                    };
                    let stdout = Stdio::piped();

                    let output = Command::new(command)
                        .args(args)
                        .stdout(stdout)
                        .stdin(stdin)
                        .spawn();

                    match output {
                        Ok(o) => previous_command = Some(Stdio::from(o.stdout.unwrap())),
                        Err(e) => {
                            previous_command = None;
                            eprintln!(" Err: {}", e);
                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    let stdin = match previous_command {
                        None => Stdio::inherit(),
                        Some(o) => o,
                    };
                    let output = Command::new(command)
                        .args(args)
                        .stdin(previous_command.unwrap())
                        .output()
                        .expect("???");
                    &mut resultat.push_str(
                        str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).expect("Could not convert command to str"),
                    );
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return resultat;
}
```

The goal is to take a string containing a shell command that my or may not contain pipes, execute them and return the result.

I use previous_command in the case of a pipe to store the output of the previous command and reuse it; however, I can't seem to reassign it without ending up with "use of moved value":

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value
  --> src/lib.rs:59:34
   |
30 |         let mut previous_command = None;
   |             -------------------- move occurs because `previous_command` has type `Option<Stdio>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
59 |                             Some(o) => o,
   |                                  ^ value used here after move
...
83 |                             .stdin(previous_command.unwrap())
   |                                                     -------- `previous_command` moved due to this method call, in previous iteration of loop
```

I have tried using as_mut() to reassign value, but to no avail... Any idea?

I have tried using as_mut() such as:

```
Ok(o) => previous_command.as_mut() = &mut Some(Stdio::from(o.stdout.unwrap())),
```

but end up having "cannot assign to this expression".

Also tried wrapping it up in a vector, but could not get to manage.

Comment: Nitpick: your `match command` is entirely redundant.

Comment: I shortened the example, which indeed makes it redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that each time `previous_command` is moved from it is also set back, except in the last iteration of the loop; but the compiler cannot distinguish the last iteration from previous iterations, and it complains that you may enter the `if` after it was moved from by the `else` in the previous iteration.

The fix is simple: just to make the compiler happy, assign `previous_command = None;` at the end of the `else` block.

This will reveal another (unrelated) borrow error, but it is pretty easy to solve. I will leave it as an exercise to you :)